# Why doesn't Medium Armor Master include a stat bump?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, armor, designer-reasons

Medium Armor Master is the only armor feat that does not include a stat bump. Why is this? Has there been any statement from the designers or rules-makers about the decision to omit a stat bump from this feat?

Comment: @Szega Heavy Armor Master: "Increase your Strength score by 1, to a maximum of 20". It's a valid question.

Comment: @keithcurtis I stand corrected.

Comment: Despite being revised to be specifically about designer statements, the question is primarily drawing answers with no founding in such statements. I don't know why this post is matching the criteria for the "primarily opinion-based" hold reason, but I can't deny that it does. Accordingly, I've put this on hold. Perhaps while it's held someone can figure out what is wrong with the question such that it's being answered this way, and correct the problem.